# .net 4.0 Adoption Rate

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

What is the adoption rate of .net 4.0?

When will it be on Windows Update?

I heard that it is smaller than 3.5, does that mean if I install .net 4.0, it will decrease the space used by the framework?

If I make an application in 3.5 and it runs on a computer that has 4.0, will my application get some of the optimizations that 4.0 uses?

Comment: Shouldn't we give it more than a day to see what happens?

Comment: As of Sept 7 here's what I know based on my user base of very normal, non-technical users.  These are numbers for the highest framework version they have installed.  3.35% have 4.0 installed. 50.8% have 3.5 installed (meaning they also have 2.0 and 3.0 installed).  10.2% have 3.0 installed. 18% have 2.0 installed. 17.5%  don't have anything higher than 1.1 installed (100% have 1.1 installed since that's what our app requires).  For me right now I think a move to 2.0 would be a sure bet, 3.5 would require half my customers to upgrade. 4.0 isn't common enough yet and has a huge disk requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You'll find most people probably won't install it until they have to use something that needs it.
2. It's an optional update on Windows update as far as I know. Optional updates tend to be ignored by a lot of people.
3. The install is small, but it won't make your .NET install any smaller. It will increase.
4. No. It will run on the .NET 3.5 platform. To use .net4 features etc you have to convert it to .net4.

Comment: 3. To clarify - the installer is small, only 48MB or so for the full framework.  The install itself is huge!  The 4.0 installer download page lists the disk requirements as 850MB and in my testing, after the install finished, it used over 700MB of my disk.  I find that to be mindbogglingly big and will likely prevent us from converting our apps to it until there's a bigger installed based.  Not ready to tell my customers they need nearly a GB free to install our new version.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of size, the Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile is what your users will need to install to run 4.0 applications and it's a 41MB download ( http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5AD0459-CBCC-4B4F-97B6-FB17111CF544&displaylang=en  ) so still not exactly 'small'. It's much better than the 3.5 client profile though, which varied in size depending on what you presently had installed but could be 100MB+

Comment: That's not strictly true. The Client Profile is what users will need to run 4.0 applications built against the subset of the framework that is contained in the Client Profile. Otherwise, if the application uses APIs that are not in the Client Profile, they will need the full framework.

Answer (score 0):

If people are installing over the Internet the web installer, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5765d7a8-7722-4888-a970-ac39b33fd8ab, which is 868 KB can be a better experience. This is a small installer that gets up and running quickly. Then during the installation it downloads only what you need for the machine it is running on. For example, on x86 the downloadd is around 28 MBs.

In addition, in the standalone instructions there are links for x86 and ia64 standalone installers. Although unless you can guarantee you will only support x86 machines for example you should use the web or x64 installer standalone installer. You cannot install x86 only on x64 machines.